# trouble tracking a session in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mixpanel

I'm having an issue counting sessions in Mixpanel for my Rails app. Basically, I'm firing a "Session" mixpanel tracking event every time someone visits a page from an external URL (not mydomain.com).

So I have something like this in my application_controller.rb before hook:

```
def count_session
    referral = request.referer
    root_url = Figaro.env.root_uri

    ### If there's a referral and it includes the root domain, then don't 
    ### track because it's the same session

    if referral && referral.include?(root_url)  
      puts "!!!! NOT TRACKED !!!!!"
    else
      puts "!!!!! TRACKED #{id}  !!!!!!"
      mixpanel.track("Session", "ID"  => current_user.id, "Version" => Figaro.env.ab_version )
    end 
  end
```

For debugging, I'm able to see "!!!!! TRACKED 4  !!!!!!" in my console when visiting the page from my account (user id: 4). But when I visit MixPanel, there's no event that shows up in the dashboard.

I can get the session event to log if I visit in an incognito browser (with id: nil) OR if I visit incognito, then explicitly login to my account. But the goal is to have the event register any time a user visits from an external url.

My other mixpanel events are working fine. Any idea why the session event would not be firing in this instance? How should I go about further debugging this?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using [Mengpaneel](https://github.com/DouweM/mengpaneel) for ruby implementation, here's my setup:

initializers/mengpaneel.rb:

```
Mengpaneel.configure do |config|
  config.token = Figaro.env.mixpanel_token
end
```

application_controller.rb:

```
before_action :setup_mixpanel
before_action :count_session

 def setup_mixpanel
    return unless user_signed_in?

    mengpaneel.setup do
        mixpanel.identify(current_user.id)

        mixpanel.people.set(
          "ID"              => current_user.id,
          "$email"          => current_user.email,
          "$created"        => current_user.created_at,
          "$last_login"     => current_user.current_sign_in_at
        )
    end
  end
```

Comment: FYI: `current_user ? id = current_user.id : id = nil` can be better expressed `id = current_user ? current_user.id : nil`. Even better, you can get rid of the ternary operator and use `mixpanel.track("Session", "ID"  => current_user.id)` since `track` appears to accept a `nil` value.

Comment: @Mohamad but if no current_user, then wouldn't current_user.id throw an error?

Comment: Yes, it would--please ignore the latter part of my comment, but the earlier advice still stands about simplifying the ternary operator. :D

Comment: @JacksonCunningham - How did you build mixpanel object? I assume you are sending event using mixpanel's ruby client? In that case, the first argument is trakcing id and then type of event.

Comment: @BroiSatse See my edit. I'm using Mengpaneel which automatically attaches the mixpanel event to a user if user exists

Comment: @JacksonCunningham - Upvote for showing me new gem. :) Are you able to send any tracking events?

Comment: Yes, all of my other events are tracking, e.g.:  mixpanel.track("Notification Created",  "Movie"  => @movie.title)  works perfectly

Comment: You could use `current_user.try(:id)`. Can you paste the rest of your AppliationController. Do you have the `include Mengpaneel::Controller` as well?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why the session event would not be firing in this instance? How should I go about further debugging this?

To answer the debugging side of your question, I'd start by ensuring I'm sending this event in the right way.

Add logging everywhere! In mengpaneel's track method:

```
def track(event, properties = {})
  return if @disable_all_events || @disabled_events.include?(event)

  properties = @properties.merge(properties)

  super(@distinct_id, event, properties)
end
```

I'd check what `@disable_all_events` and `@disabled_events` are set to, by updating my local gem to log those attributes. I'd also log the result of calling `super`, in case it returns some kind of error response. Or using the ruby `debugger`.

I know you said other calls were working, so perhaps it's just this call which is getting dropped silently.

Another option would be to figure out how to get a proxy in the middle of the HTTP requests (i.e. Charles).